Proof of Polynomial Behavior in Sequence of Random Variables

Problem statement: Let $X_0, \xi_{i, j}, \epsilon_k$ (i, j, k ∈ N) be independent, non-negative integer random variables. Suppose that $\xi_{i, j}$ (i, j ∈ N) have the same distribution, $\epsilon_k$ (k ∈ N) also have the same distribution.
$\mathbb{E}(\xi_{1,1})=1$ , $\mathbb{E}(X_0^l)<\infty$ , $\mathbb{E}(\xi_{1,1}^l)<\infty$ , $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_1^l)<\infty$ for some $l\in\mathbb{N}$
Consider the random variable $X_n := \epsilon_n + \sum_{j=1}^{X_{n-1}} \xi_{n,j}$ (n ∈ N) , where $\sum_{j=1}^0 \xi_{n,j} :=0$
Introduce the sequence $M_n := X_n-X_{n-1}-\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_n)$ (n ∈ N)
Prove that there is a polynomial P of degree $\leq l/2$ such that $\mathbb{E}(M_n^l) = P_l(n)$ $(n ∈ N).$

My attempt
Very beautiful problem! Here is the partial solution for the case when $l=2^k$ for some non-negative integer $k$.
We will use the following elementary fact repeatedly without mentioning it:
If $Y$ is a non-negative integer valued random variable and if $\mathbf{E}[Y^k] < \infty$ for some $k \in \mathbf{N}$ then $\mathbf{E}[ Y^{d} ] < \infty$ for every positive integer $d \le k$.
Notice that $X_n - X_{n-1} = \epsilon_n + \sum_{j=1}^{X_{n-1}} (\xi_{n,j}-1)$. Let $t_{i,j} = \xi_{i,j}-1$ for all $i,j$.
Then by the given conditions $t_{i,j}$ are independent, identically distributed, have mean zero, and $\mathbf{E}[|t_{1,1}|^l] < \infty$ (because $|t_{1,1}| \le |\xi_{1,1}| + 1 = \xi_{1,1} + 1$ as $\xi_{i,j}$ are non-negative valued and have finite $l$-th moments).
Thus, $M_n = \epsilon_n - \mathbf{E}[\epsilon_n] + \sum_{i=1}^{X_{n-1}} t_{n,i}$
This implies $\mathbf{E}[M_n] = 0$ for all $n$ and hence in particular the claim is true for $l=1$.
Now, we prove the claim when $l = 2^k$ for some $k$.
Suppose for some $k \ge 1$ the claim is true with $l = 2^k$, then we also have variance of $M_n^{l}$ = $\mathbf{E}[ (M_n^l - \mathbf{E}[M_n^l])^2]$ and hence the variance of $M_n ^{l}$ must be a polynomial $q_{l}(n)$ of degree $ \le 2 \cdot l/2 = l$; now write $\mathbf{E}[M_n^{2l}]$ as
$\mathbf{E}[M_n^{2l}] = \mathbf{E}[ (M_n^{l})^{2}]$ = $\textsf{var}(M_n^l) + (\mathbf{E}[M_n^l])^2$ and by our induction hypothesis and the ensuing deductions this is a sum of two polynomials each having degree $\le l$, and this proves the claim for $l = 2^{k+1}$ provided of course that the $2^{k+1}$ th moment of $t_{1,1}$ and of $X_0$ are finite.
So this proves that the claim is true whenever $l = 2^{k}$ for some non-negative integer $k$.
